# SQLCipher - Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated error

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

My question is very much similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3068320/394933) but slightly different. I get the following error when I simply try to query everything in my table that has been encrypted by [SQLCiper](https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/).

```
 12-29 11:37:54.329: E/Cursor(10837): Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/data/com.company.myapp/databases/data, table = data_table, query = SELECT rowid, data FROM data_table
 12-29 11:37:54.329: E/Cursor(10837): info.guardianproject.database.sqlcipher.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
 12-29 11:37:54.329: E/Cursor(10837):   at info.guardianproject.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteCursor.<init>(SQLiteCursor.java:225)
 12-29 11:37:54.329: E/Cursor(10837):   at info.guardianproject.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:53)
 12-29 11:37:54.329: E/Cursor(10837):   at info.guardianproject.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
 12-29 11:37:54.329: E/Cursor(10837):   at info.guardianproject.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1289)
 12-29 11:37:54.329: E/Cursor(10837):   at info.guardianproject.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1243)
 12-29 11:37:54.329: E/Cursor(10837):   at info.guardianproject.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1325)
 12-29 11:37:54.329: E/Cursor(10837):   at com.company.appName.DatabaseManager.queryAllItems(DatabaseManager.java:105)
```

I thought that this error would only happen if I forgot to close the `Cursor` after I was done using it but it seems that I'm getting this error even before I'm able to start using it.

Here's the code that's in the `queryAllItems()` method:

```
public Cursor queryAllItems() {
    return database.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_DATA}, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: The error indicates that the `Cursor` "was opened here". To me, that means you successfully called `queryAllItems()`, but never then closed the `Cursor`, and it is telling you where you created the `Cursor` in the first place.

Comment: You're totally right, I put in a couple of debug markers and noticed that the error was happening after all the querying was done. I guess I was misled by that stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was misled by the stack trace and it appeared that I just need to call `Cursor.deactivate()` and `Cursor.close()` after all my operations on the query were done.

Answer (score 0):

After creating cursor, if you call `startManagingCursor(c);` will resolve the issue. Here 'c' is cursor reference.