# Cursor finalized without prior close() warning. what does it mean?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

LogCat keeps on showing me a

> Cursor finalized without prior close()

warning.

I was using SQLite on a previous version of the app, but don't use it anymore.

I tried to find the cause for this warning with no luck. some Google and Stackoverflow references say it's related to the db.

What does this warning mean? should I ignore it?

I could supply a sample code but I don't have an idea which part of my app causes this. there is also no stack trace added.

**EDIT**: Apparently a cursor is being used by a 3rd party dependency that I'm using, which is causing this warning.

Comment: there is a cursor that is dereferenced (and therefore collected by the garbage collector) but that you never `close()` before dereferencing. Hence the warning. Most of the time, I consider it is quite safe to ignore it, and quite a pain to track it down.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29846562/262789 for how to resolve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exactly what your warning says, you have some cases that you didn't use

```
cursor.close();
```

Comment: I don't use a cursor in any place. where could a cursor be used?

Comment: Do you use any external sqllite connection library?

Comment: No, I did an attempt with sqlite on a previous version but there's no trace for it that I could find...