# android- when i set my alarm using sqlite database get error

Tags: android, sqlite, alarm

i am new on android and i am develop an alarm aplication i have found this error when i set alarm

```
Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed.
database = /data/data/com.time/databases/Salarm.db, table = ASTimer,
query = SELECT _id, description, altime, status, frequency, prealarm FROM ASTimer WHERE status='ON'
```

Code :

```
public Cursor getAllAlarmON()
{
Log.i("alarm","Fetching records from the database...");

Cursor cursor= db.query(tableName, new String[]{"_id","description","altime","status","frequency","prealarm"}, "status='ON'", null, null, null, null);

return cursor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you close your cursor using `cursor.close()` before closing the database or use `startManaginCursor(cursor)`.

---

Take a look at : [finalizing-a-cursor-that-has-not-been-deactivated-or-closed-non-fatal-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068320/finalizing-a-cursor-that-has-not-been-deactivated-or-closed-non-fatal-error)